# Configurar vs code para proyectos angular

Tags: angular, typescript, vscode, eslint

Estoy tratando de buscar cual es la forma de evitar mensajes de alertas que no sean aquellos que sean dirigidos a errores como tal. Tratando de seguir unos tutoriales para aprender angular me he encontrado que el editor, en mi caso **vs code**, marca muchos errores, pero estos son de advertencia.

Como por ejemplo:

`Doctype must be declared first.(doctype-first)`

Donde claramente dice que se necesita `DOCTYPE` como cualquier archivo html, pero cabe recordar que en angular, solo se hace eso en el `index` o archivo principal de `html`.

`The attribute name of [ *ngIf ] must be in lowercase.(attr-lowercase)`

Y en este caso dice que debe ser todo en letras miniscula, cuando son metodos encasulados del mismo `framework` y esta estipulado de esa forma

[image: 1]

#### EL otro es

`Properties should be separated by semicolons (semicolon)tslint(1)`

Cuando claramente tiene formato de JSON, el cual como objeto va separado por comas, y no por punto y coma.

[image: 2]

[Repositorio ngLearning](https://github.com/PterPmnta/ngLearning)

Comment: No se si sea lo que estas buscando. Pero para trabajar con Angular en Visual Studio Code te dejo una lista de Snippets y Plugins que facilitan mucho, ademas interpretan mejor ese tipo de mensajes de advertencias:

* Angular 2 TypeScript Emmet.
* Angular 5 Snippets – (TypeScript, Html, Angular Material…)
* Angular Language Service
* Angular v5 Snippets
* Angular2-inline

Comment: **Otros muy buenos**

* Bootstrap 4 & Font Awesome snippets
* HTML CSS Support
* JavaScript(ES6) code snippets
* JS-CSS-HTML Formatter
* JSHint
* Prettier – Code Formatter
* Terminal
* TSLint
* TypeScript Hero
* TypeScript Importer

Comment: TSLint lo tengo, y según el paquete que se instala cuando uno crea un proyecto nuevo, tiene ya unas configuraciones, pero no funciona. Por otro lado, los plugins de snippets no solucionan esa parte

Comment: Puedes instalar todo con solo un plugin:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.angular-essentials&wt.mc_id=devto-blog-jopapa

Comment: Ademas ten en cuenta que  la definición de un interface no es un archivo JSON otra cosa es que luego al utilizarlo si recibas o trabajes con datos en formato JSON

Comment: No he dicho que sea JSON, si no la notación, la estructura de este, claramente la extensión es **.ts**

Comment: Lo primero te pasa porque es probable que tengas instalado algún linter HTML que te esté dando esos conflictos porque obviamente no reconoce sintaxis de Angular. Lo segundo es por [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) que es linter que usa Angular por defecto. Todos esos warnings los puedes desactivar en el archivo `tslint.json`. Te recomiendo instalar la extensión Angular Language Service.

Comment: Ya instale ese plugin hace mucho

Comment: Quiero remarcar lo comentado por @KarlosCode: una interfaz no sigue el formato JSON, no se está declarando un objeto sino sus propiedades y los tipos de éstas. Lo normal es separarlas por comas, como en la declaración de variables en una función.

Answer (score 3):

El fichero **TSLINT** es el que se encarga de dar claridad y uniformidad a nuestro código, sobretodo cuando trabajamos en equipo. Cuando se empieza un proyecto, se suele tener una reunión de cómo se va a programar (en cuanto a estilos). Todas estas reglas quedan reflejas y configuradas en este archivo para que todo el equipo programe con los mismos estilos.

En tu caso de interface, prueba a añadir en el fichero `tslint.json` lo siguiente:

```
    "rules": {
        "semicolon": [
            true, 
            "always", 
            "ignore-interfaces"
        ],
```

Te dejo un enlace por si quieres configurar más cosas. A veces la configuración del tslint puede ser un poco tediosa, pero conviene invertir un poco de tiempo al comenzar el proyecto.
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/semicolon/

Comment: Perdona, tienes que añadirlo dentro de rules
"rules": {
        "semicolon": 
        [true, "always", "ignore-interfaces"],

Comment: puedes [edit] tu respuesta y agrega lo que explicas puedes añadir una imagen donde se encuentra "rules"

Comment: falta explicar que ese archivo deberia estar en la raiz del repositorio

Comment: Gracias, en mi caso desactive un plugin que se llama `HTML-HINT`, y ya no marca esas advertencias